# I am getting multiple similar results from a like query, how can I combine results?

Tags: sql-server

The results of the below give me multiple values because of versions like
Bomgar v1.2
Bomgar v1.3

I would like them to combine into just one row.

```
select distinct ARPDisplayName0  

from v_HS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

where ARPDisplayName0 like 'Bomgar%'
```

Comment: Seems like you would have to parse or map the values in ARPDisplayName0.   Without sample data and desired results, it is impossible to answer

Comment: I changed not like to like. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to put all `Bomgar` in the same bucket, but you still want all the other rows. So you need a `CASE` expression

```sql
select distinct
    CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0 like 'Bomgar%' THEN 'Bomgar' ELSE ARPDisplayName0 END ARPDisplayName0  
from v_HS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE;
```